# page title gets always null

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am stuck with such an issue. I have written a whole code which is necessary to get that page title. like writing the line

`<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>`

but this line do works only on my login page and not any other page. at all other pages the title comes once but gets cleared as soon as whole page gets loaded. i am not getting any JS which is stopping the title to come.
I don't know which other information i should give to you. Please ask me what more thing i should give you

Comment: Is this code existing in your _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: yes it is in the layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you always declare `ViewBag.Title = "PAGE_TITLE";` in each of your **Action** method per Controller

Comment: whomp... that worked. Please tell me but why this thing is not working when  i give that from my cshtml

Comment: Because your _Layout.cshtml that loads the `@ViewBag.Title` in your title tag is loaded first than your .cshtml in your view. That's why you have to declare the ViewBag in your action method rather than in .cshtml